# Need help using regular expressions to constrain route

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I best state that the value of L1Cat and L2Cat must not be an integer value/not consist of only 0-9 numbers to keep the page value from being assigned to them with some URL requests.

```
                    routes.MapRoute(
        "Store5", // Route name
        "{RootPointer}/{L1Cat}/{L2Cat}/{page}", // URL with parameters
        new
        {
            controller = "Store",
            action = "Index",
            RootPointer = UrlParameter.Optional,
            page =1
        },
        new { controller = "Store", action = "Index", page = @"\d+" });
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?  So `L1Cat` and `L2Cat` can only contain non-numeric characters?

Comment: Yes. Or better yet can contain numeric, but not only numeric. Only if mixed with alphabetical.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@".*[^\d].*"` for both L1Cat and L2Cat. It means that somewhere in the url part there must be non-decimal character. Normally `[^\d]` would be enough of course, but the default Route wraps the regex constraints in `^` and `$`, so just `[^\d]` would capture single non-digit parts only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 !Regex.IsMatch(url,@"/\d+/")
```